# How to use twitter REST api along with railscast 241

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, twitter

REST noob here:

I'm using the code from ryan bates rails cast #241

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth
```

I can authenticate with my user just fine....

Now I want to display the last tweet I made on the views/articles/index.html.erb page....

I want to just want to display the data from this REST api thing..."https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline"

How do I change this code in the most simplest way?

```
<% title "Articles" %>

<div id="articles">

    <!-- TODO grab my tweets with GET Statuses/home_timeline -->




<% for article in @articles %>
  <h2>
    <%= link_to article.name, article %>
    <span class="comments">(<%= pluralize(article.comments.size, 'comment') %>)</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="created_at">on <%= article.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %></div>
  <div class="content"><%= simple_format(article.content) %></div>
<% end %>
</div>

<p><%= link_to "New Article", new_article_path %></p>
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a loot at *twitter gem*: http://sferik.github.com/twitter/

You can grab a user's timeline like: `timeline = Twitter.user_timeline( twitter_username )`

Comment: Bingo! I'll have to create a blog tutorial to help myself and others...I did this a year ago but forgot what I did :(